# Getting response object from Axios

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, axios

We have a function that sends user info(SSN) to retrieve additional information about the user. I need to retrieve the user ID, which should be returned something like this in the response:

employee:[{
firstName:"Jon",
lastName: "Doe",
id: ""1234
}]

The function we have ends at the console log ('sent data') and then throws a 400 error and doesn't return the response. Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong? axiosInstance pulls the session token and console logs it correctly. All of the required parameters are in console log so I think it's a formatting issue possibly

```
exports.returnIds = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 1 minutes').onRun((context) => {
  return admin.firestore().collection('Submissions').orderBy("user", "asc").startAt(1000)
     .get()
       .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          let EncryptedSSN  = doc.data().ssn
          let decryptSSN  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(EncryptedSSN, '####')
          var ssn = decryptSSN.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
          var clientId = "####" 
          let docId = doc.data().id
              try {
                axiosInstance.request({
                  url: 'https://website/services/rest/users/getBySSN',
                  method: 'post',
                  data: {ssn, clientId},
                  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                }) 
                console.log('sent data')
                return response.data
                .then(response => {
                  const userId = response.data;
                  console.log('data', userId);
                  return admin.firestore().collection('Submissions').doc(docId).update({
                  userId: payrollId
            })
                }).catch(err => {
                  console.error(err);
              });
              } catch (err) {
                  console.error(err);
              }            
      })
    })
})
```

Comment: Right after `console.log('sent data')` you have a `return response.data.then(...)`. Shouldn't the `.then(...)` be attached to the axios request?

Comment: `response.data` is not a promise. So it doesn't have a `.then()`. Did you forget to include the error(s) you're getting in console when the above code runs?

Comment: @tao The only errors I'm getting is "Error: Request failed with status code 400" and "Error: Process exited with code 16 at process.". No additional info. I moved response.data to inside the .then() and I'm still receiving the same error